# Close or delete file which is in open mode

Tags: c#, file

all I am  writing a CSV file through below code ,

```
  using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(AbsolutePathAndFileName))
  {
        //write header line
        int iColCount = TheDataTable.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(TheDataTable.Columns[i]);
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(separator);
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        //write rows
        foreach (DataRow dr in TheDataTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    string data = dr[i].ToString();
                    data = data.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace(",", " ");
                    sw.Write(data);
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(separator);
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

After that I will open that file for review.  Now, file is in open mode.

But while I again regenerate that file than it disallows me and says that File is being used by another process.

Is there any solution for this problem ? I need to delete or close that file

Comment: When you say "open that file for review" means you open it with notepad or something? If so you need to close that before regeneration.

Comment: Yes that is I am asking, How can I close that file

Comment: You can't. What you might want to suggest to your users is generate another file called ".1.txt. Or instead, display the text results in a text box which can easily update.

Comment: Looking all the comments and descriptions of your situations I think the best way is to inform your user to close the file. Before you start writing you can check if the file is already open then you can pop a message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement to make sure it is disposed.

Are you opening the file in readOnly mode when required?

```
using (FileStream f = File.Open("c:\\software\\code.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
{

}
```

Comment: please check my updated code , I have used StreamWriter in a using statement.. still I am getting same response. And I am opening that file using Process.Start(fileName); line

Comment: Is there any other idea to Kill a process or something. Need to kill process of particular that csv file not all csv or excel file.

Comment: I think you could loop through the running processes and kill notepad, but this would confuse the user if they wanted to make changes or used something Notepad++ etc. I think the easiest option, would be to append the date and time onto the generated file. Or if the user always had to open up these files, maybe use a different user interface.

Comment: @ForeverDebugging but don't you think this will close other opened note pads as well.

Comment: That's true. Hence why you should generate a file with a different name so you don't need to go and close it.